# Error while implementing a windows runtime interface for local consumption while porting from c++/cx to c++/winrt

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

**Update**:

Based on Ryan Shepherd's reply, I changed my code to:

```
class DerivedClass : winrt::implements<DerivedClass, BaseClass> {
public:
DerivedClass(winrt::FrameworkElement& control) : 
5===>implements_type(control) {}

static winrt::com_ptr<DerivedClass> from(winrt::FrameworkElement control) { 
    control ? control.Tag().try_as<SvgCanvasController>() : nullptr;
}
}
```

Now I get an error:

> no instance of constructor "winrt::implements<D, I, ...>::implements [with D=DerivedClass, I=BaseClass]" matches the argument list argument types are: (winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement).

I do have BaseClass Constructor defined which takes in &FrameworkElement as an argument. So I am not sure what I am getting this error.

**Original**:

I had this in C++/CX:

```
ref class DerivedClass sealed : public BaseClass {
public:
explicit DerivedClass(Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement^ &control)
    : BaseClass(control) {}

static DerivedClass from(Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement^ control) {
    return control ? dynamic_cast<DerivedClass>(control->Tag) : nullptr;
}   
}
```

when I try to convert this to c++/winrt

```
class DerivedClass : winrt::implements<DerivedClass, BaseClass> {
public:
1===>DerivedClass(winrt::FrameworkElement& control) : BaseClass(control) 
2===>{
}

static DerivedClass from(winrt::FrameworkElement control) { 
    if (control)
 3===>       return control.Tag().try_as<SvgCanvasController>();
    else
 4===>       return nullptr;
}
```

There are a few issues here I want to discuss and understand. As it is written above, I get the following errors:

1

> BaseClass is not a non-static data member or base class of class DerivedClass

2

> default constructor of winrt::implements<DerivedClass, BaseClass> cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

3

> No suitable user defined conversion from winrt::impl::com_ref<DerivedClass> to DerivedClass

4

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from std::nullptr_t to DerivedClass

Would love some thoughts on these errors.

I understand I create a DerivedClass object as

```
auto obj = winrt::make<DerivedClass>();
```

Questions:

1. How do I write the constructor properly?
2. How can i pass the argument to the base class constructor like I do in C++/CX?
3. How can I deal with the errors in the from() function definition.

Comment: The default access modifier when driving a `class` is `private`. Either make that a `struct` or specify that you want to drive `public`ly.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the first error, `DerivedClass` doesn't inherit from `BaseClass`, it inherits from `winrt::implements<DerivedClass, BaseClass>`, which then derives from `BaseClass`. A grandchild class can't directly initialize its grandparent - it most go through its immediate base type. Fortunately, C++/WinRT provides a helper type in `winrt::implements` so you don't have to repeat all those template params. So, your constructor should look like this:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;

struct BaseType : implements<BaseType, IInspectable>
{
    explicit BaseType(FrameworkElement const&)
    {}
};

struct DerivedType : implements<DerivedType, BaseType>
{
    explicit DerivedType(FrameworkElement const& arg)
        : implements_type(arg)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    make<DerivedType>(FrameworkElement{ nullptr });
}
```

This code compiles successfully for me.

The other three errors are due to the fact that you are attempting to return an *implementation* type directly on the stack. These objects are reference counted, and must be allocated on the heap, which you appear to understand due to calling out `winrt::make`. But the rest of the equation is that instead of returning a `DerivedClass`, you need to return `winrt::com_ptr<DerivedClass>`, resulting in something like this:

```cpp
static winrt::com_ptr<Derived> from(winrt::FrameworkElement const& arg)
{
  return arg ? arg.Tag().try_as<DerivedClass>() : nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. when I use implements_type(control), I get the following error: "no instance of constructor winrt::implements<D, I, ...>::implements [with D=DerivedClass, I=BaseClass]" matches the argument list            argument types are: (winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement). I do have BaseClass Constructor defined which takes in &FrameworkElement as an argument. So I am not sure what I am missing. Or if my understanding there is still lacking.

Comment: I suspect there is more to your example than is posted. I've updated the code above to mimic the code in your question, and it compiles successfully for me.